# react-google-maps HeatmapLayer: Cannot read property 'maps' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

```js
import React from 'react'
const { compose, withProps, withStateHandlers } = require('recompose')
const {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  LatLng
} = require('react-google-maps')
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { MapInfoWindow } from './MapInfoWindow'
import HeatmapLayer from "react-google-maps/lib/components/visualization/HeatmapLayer";

class HeatMap extends React.Component {

    render() {

        var data = [new window.google.maps.LatLng(40.705076, -74.00916)]

        const HomeMap = compose(withScriptjs, withGoogleMap)(props => {
          (
          <GoogleMap defaultZoom={9} defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.705076, lng: -74.00916 }}>
              {props.pools ? (
                props.pools.map(pool => <MapInfoWindow key={pool.id} pool={pool} />)
              ) : (
                  <div />
                )}
            <HeatmapLayer data={data}/>
          </GoogleMap>
        )})

        return (
          <div className='googleMap'>
            <HomeMap
              googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=###=3.exp&libraries=visualization,geometry,drawing,places"
                  loadingElement={<div style={{height: `100%`}} />}
                  containerElement={<div style={{height: `600px`}} />}
                  mapElement={<div style={{height: `100%`}} />}
            />
          </div>
        )
    }
}

export default connect(mapState, mapDispatch)(HeatMap)
```

I've been trying to make the Heatmap work but keep getting an error:

> `maps` is undefined at `new window.google.maps.LatLng(40.705076, -74.00916)`.

I've also tried with `new google.maps.LatLng(40.705076, -74.00916)` but I'am getting the same error.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `new google.maps.LatLng` inside of the `withScriptJs` render function. Having it outside of the render function is causing the browser to try to use the Google Maps APIs before the script has finished loading. Something like the example below.

```
const HomeMap = compose(withScriptjs, withGoogleMap)(props => {
  const data = [new window.google.maps.LatLng(40.705076, -74.00916)];
  return (
    <GoogleMap defaultZoom={9} defaultCenter={{ lat: 40.705076, lng: -74.00916 }}>
      <HeatmapLayer data={data}/>
    </GoogleMap>
  );
});
```